# titlesec – How to avoid extra space before \part at top of page

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec, article

I'm trying to modify the way different headings are shown in my article by using the `titlesec` package. However, for `\part` there is some extra vertical space at the start of a page which does not appear for `\section`.

Where does this space come from and how can I get rid of it? Please note, that I do want the space if `\part` or `\section`occurs in the middle of a page, just like it works already for `\section`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\large}{\partname~\Alph{part}}{2ex}{}{}
\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{*5}{*2}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{\arabic{section}}{2ex}{}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*5}{*2}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\part{Part Part Part}
\blindtext

\section{Section Section Section}
\blindtext
\newpage

\part{Part Part Part}
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\newpage

\section{Section Section Section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make  `part` belong to the same class as `\section`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\large}{\partname~\Alph{part}}{2ex}{}{}
\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{*5}{*2}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{\arabic{section}}{2ex}{}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*5}{*2}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\part{Part Part Part}
\blindtext

\section{Section Section Section}
\blindtext
\newpage

\part{Part Part Part}
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\newpage

\section{Section Section Section}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That helps indeed. Any idea why the extra space is there in the first place? Without any modifications (e.g. without `titlesec`) the extra space is not there for `\part`.

Comment: I guess this is due to the default class  for `\part`. See  §3.9  of the documentation, *Creating new levels and changing the class*, and especially footnote n° 19.

Comment: I did read the manual but missed the footnote. Thanks for pointing me to this. The 'part' class indeed gives the weird default behaviour. Still, it makes little sense to me. Especially given the fact that the unmodified `\part` works as expected. Maybe I should use this opportunity to learn more by reading the sources :-)

Comment: That's because it has by default the behaviour of \part in the `book` class, I guess (on a single page).